# device to android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Can I setup a pc to act as a virtual serial port to mimic a device using SPP bluetooth profile that I need to talk to an android phone?

The device would not have no way receiving the UUID that it needs to be listening for to connect to my phone.
I saw the "reflection" method being used to avoid UUID. Is this how to communicate with devices agnostic to android's communication process?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the final part of your question.
For the first part however, you can. You just need a BT adapter inside your PC/laptop, Windows,Python installed, and a little library called [PyBluez](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/).

After installing everything, you can communicate via SPP with client-server roles established as you like (PC server & Android client or viceversa). You have examples for both those:

- PyBluez [server example](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py) and [client example](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/simple/rfcomm-client.py)
- Android examples [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices)

You have to have a UUID, but, in the examples above, it is the standard UUID for SPP. Basically SPP is RFCOMMM with this UUID:

***00001101-0000-100­0-8000-00805F9B34FB***

Don't forget to vote if useful!